# When to normalize data?

Tags: anova, inference, normalization, nonparametric

The purpose of the study is to compare males and females in the rate of fatigue for muscle strength. Muscle strength was measured at baseline (PRE), the mid-point of fatigue, and after fatigue. I plan to run a 2-way (sex x time) ANOVA. It is well know that males are stronger and indeed baseline strength values were higher in this group. Should the absolute or normalized (to baseline) values be analyzed? Is this decision solely based on whether it is expected that baseline strength is influential for the degree of fatigue?

Comment: You might be interested in a model called difference in differences.

Comment: What about individual ANOVAs; one for men and one for women?

Comment: That just tells you how the before and after groups compare to one another, how how the differences compare.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am limited to ANOVA but this is a common test for this kind of work. Papers are just very ambiguous on whether they analyze normalized or absolute values. I do need to directly compare (assess interaction) the groups over time.